# merge two fields into an object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I am trying to merge two fields
here is my collection

```
db.Acc_Details.findOne()
{ 
    "_id": ObjectId("577f43fe748646cc91370713"), 
    "Acc_Id": 1, 
    "Name": "xxxxx", 
    "Phone": NumberLong("123456789"), 
    "Email": "xxxxxx@gmail.com" 
}
```

Now, I want to combine `Phone` and `Email` into `contact` and update this collection

```
db.Acc_Details.findOne()
{ 
    "_id": ObjectId("577f43fe748646cc91370713"), 
    "Acc_Id": 1, 
    "Name": "xxxxx", 
    "Contact": {
        "Phone": NumberLong("123456789"), 
        "Email": "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
    } 
}
```

This is what I have tried but I don't know if it's right or not:

```
db.Acc_Details.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "Contact": {
                "$map": {
                    input: { $literal: ["p1", "p2"] },
                    as: "p",
                    in: {
                        $cond: [
                           { $eq: ["$$p", "p1"] },
                           "$Phone",
                           "$Email"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$Contact" }
])
```

Result is

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("577f43fe748646cc91370713"), "Contact" : NumberLong("12356789") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("577f43fe748646cc91370713"), "Contact" : "xxxxxx@gmail.com" }
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bit overkill. A much simpler pipeline follows:

```
db.Acc_Details.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "Acc_Id": 1, 
            "Name": 1, 
            "Contact": {
                "Phone": "$Phone", 
                "Email": "$Email"
            } 
        }
    }
])
```

---

To update the table with the new schema, you need to leverage your updates with the [**`bulkWrite()`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) API which is more efficient for the task. Consider the following bulk update operation where you just iterate using the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)** cursor and update the fields as:

```
var ops = [];
db.Acc_Details.find().snapshot().forEach(function(doc) {
    ops.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": {
                "$set": { 
                    "Contact": { "Phone": doc.Phone, "Email": doc.Email }
                },
                "$unset": { "Phone": "", "Email": "" }
            }
        }
    });

    if (ops.length === 500) {
        db.Acc_Details.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }
})

if (ops.length > 0)  db.Acc_Details.bulkWrite(ops);
```

Or using the above aggregate results:

```
var ops = [];
db.Acc_Details.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "Contact": {
                "Phone": "$Phone", 
                "Email": "$Email"
            } 
        }
    }
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    ops.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": {
                "$set": { "Contact": doc.Contact },
                "$unset": { "Phone": "", "Email": "" }
            }
        }
    });

    if (ops.length === 500) {
        db.Acc_Details.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }
})

if (ops.length > 0)  db.Acc_Details.bulkWrite(ops);
```

---

Or for MongoDB 2.6.x and 3.0.x releases use this version of **[`Bulk`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/bulk-write-operations/)** operations:

```
var bulk = db.Acc_Details.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0;
db.Acc_Details.find().snapshot().forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { 
            "Contact": { "Phone": doc.Phone, "Email": doc.Email }
        },
        "$unset": { "Phone": "", "Email": "" }
    });

    if (counter % 500 === 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.Acc_Details.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if (counter % 1000 !== 0 )  bulk.execute();
```

The Bulk operations API in both cases will help reduce the IO load on the server by sending the requests only once in every 500 documents in the collection to process.